# What is the equation if that projection starts SHM on the $x$-axis from extreme position?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

Consider A particle performing Uniform Circular Motion.
We know that its projection on diameter performs SHM.
Then, if that projection starts SHM on the **y axis** from **mean position**, then $y=A\text{sin}(ωt)$
if that projection starts SHM on the **y axis** from **extreme position**, then $y=A\text{cos}(ωt)$
if that projection starts SHM on the **x axis** from **mean position**, then $x=A\text{cos}(ωt)$
Then What is the equation if that projection starts SHM on the **x axis** from **extreme position**?

Comment: Using polar co-ordinates (see the answer below) is the most general approach. But also note that any SHM that starts from an extreme position has equation $\pm A \cos (\omega t)$ and any SHM that starts from the mean position has equation $\pm A \sin (\omega t)$.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question not a "do my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 1):

Start in polar coordinates:

$$ r = A $$
$$ \theta(t) = \omega t + \theta_0 $$

where $\theta_0$ is the phase at $t=0$. Vary $\theta_0$ to create the initial position, and convert to Cartesian coordinates to find $(x(t), y(t))$.

Apply trig identities as needed.